# Why shellharden does not output background colors in Terminator?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, colors, terminator

I have installed [shellharden](https://github.com/anordal/shellharden/), a library that allows to output shell syntax issues (like missing double quotes) in a shell / bash script.

Output should highlight double quote issues with a different background color (See this scrrenshot from documentation https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anordal/shellharden/master/img/ex-artificial.png)

In default Ubuntu terminal, shellharden background colors are correctly rendered.

In [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com) shell, shellharden background colors are missing.

[image]

Legend: Default terminal at left: colors ok
Terminator at right: missing colors

The command I run was:

```
~/.cargo/bin/shellharden --syntax-suggest ~/path/to/script
```

Do you have any clue to this difference?
Should Terminator be run with any option?
Thanx for your help.

Edit after Shellharden's author answer:

- my Ubuntu version is 16.04
- my Terminator version is 0.9.8

Note: I do not have 10 reputation yet, so I cannot embed my own images. I add screenshot links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shellharden author here.

Shellharden uses 24-bit colors. It could be that your version of terminator does not support that (terminator 1.91 works here).

Wikipedia has [a list of which terminals support 24-bit color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_terminal_emulators#Capabilities).

You can try this to test if your terminal supports 24-bit colors:

```
printf '\e[1;3;4;5;48;2;176;255;255;38;2;255;128;0mcarrot in the sky with underline\e[m\n'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

My current version of Terminator is 0.9.8.
I installed the latest 1.9.1, and your test command then successfully printed colors.